# MySQL chooses to execute queries, or not, at whim

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sql-execution-plan

For a reporting output, I used to DROP and recreate a table 'mis.pr_approval_time'. but now I just TRUNCATE it.

After populating the above table with data, I run an UPDATE statement, but I have written that as a SELECT below...

```
SELECT t.account_id FROM mis.hj_approval_survey h INNER JOIN mis.pr_approval_time t ON h.country = t.country AND t.scheduled_at =
(
    SELECT MAX(scheduled_at) FROM mis.pr_approval_time 
    WHERE country = h.country 
    AND scheduled_at <= h.created_at 
    AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(h.created_at, scheduled_at)) < 91
);
```

When I run the above statement or even just...

```
SELECT t.account_id FROM mis.hj_approval_survey h INNER JOIN mis.pr_approval_time t ON h.country = t.country AND t.scheduled_at =
(
    SELECT MAX(scheduled_at) FROM mis.pr_approval_time 
    WHERE country = h.country
);
```

...it runs forever and does not seem to finish. There are only ~3,400 rows in hj_approval_survey table and 29,000 rows in pr_approval_time. I run this on an Amazon AWS instance with 15+ GB RAM.

Now, if I simply right click on pr_approval_time table and choose ALTER TABLE option, and just close without doing anything, then the above queries run within seconds.

I guess when I trigger the ALTER TABLE option and Workbench populates the table fields, it probably improves its execution plan somehow, but I am not sure why. Has anyone faced anything similar to this? How can I trigger a better execution plan check without right clicking the table and choosing 'ALTER TABLE'

**EDIT**

It may be noteworthy to mention that my organisation also uses DOMO. Originally, I had this setup as an MySQL Dataflow on DOMO, but the query would not complete on most occassions, but I have observed it finish at times.

This was the reason why I moved this query back to our AWS MySQL RDS. So the problem has not only been observed on our own MySQL RDS, but probably also on DOMO

Comment: Did you index columns involved in WHERE clause(s)? That would be the *simplest* performance tuning step.

Comment: @Littlefoot yes, both tables have index columns created and show up in the Query Plan (Explain). When I see it there it shows up with Green boxes, but the query just doesn't complete. Also, as I mentioned above 30,000 rows are barely anything, even without index columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is slow because of the correlated subquery (subquery depends on row values from parent table, meaning it has to execute for each row). I'd try and rework the pr_approval_time table slightly so it's point-in-time and then you can use the JOIN to pick the correct rows without doing a correlated subquery. Something like:

```
SELECT
    hj_approval_survey.country
,   hj_approval_survey.created_at
,   pr_approval_time.account_id
FROM
    @hj_approval_survey AS hj_approval_survey
JOIN    (
            SELECT
                current_row.country
            ,   current_row.scheduled_at AS scheduled_at_start
            ,   COALESCE( MIN( next_row.scheduled_at ), GETDATE() ) AS scheduled_at_end
            FROM
                @pr_approval_time AS current_row
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                @pr_approval_time AS next_row ON (
                    next_row.country = current_row.country
                AND next_row.scheduled_at > current_row.scheduled_at
                )
            GROUP BY
                current_row.country
            ,   current_row.scheduled_at
        ) AS pr_approval_pit ON (
            pr_approval_pit.country = hj_approval_survey.country
        AND (   hj_approval_survey.created_at >= pr_approval_pit.scheduled_at_start
            AND hj_approval_survey.created_at < pr_approval_pit.scheduled_at_end
            )
        )
JOIN    @pr_approval_time AS pr_approval_time ON (
            pr_approval_time.country = pr_approval_pit.country
        AND pr_approval_time.scheduled_at = pr_approval_pit.scheduled_at_start
        )
WHERE
        TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( hj_approval_survey.created_at, pr_approval_time.scheduled_at ) ) < 91
```

Comment: I had to change your query a bit, but it works fine. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have proper index on the columns involved  in join 
You could try refactoring  your  query using a grouped by subquery and join on country

```
  SELECT t.account_id 
  FROM mis.hj_approval_survey h 
  INNER JOIN mis.pr_approval_time t ON h.country = t.country 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT country, MAX(scheduled_at)  max_sched
        FROM mis.pr_approval_time 
        group by country
    ) z on z.contry = t.country and t.scheduled_at = z.max_sched
```

Comment: Not sure whether you understand what I was trying to do, but there isn't an exact match between approval time and survey creation time. Hence I use the sub-query to get the approval time closest to the survey creation. Approval happens first and then survey creation.

Comment: if you show a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. is more easy understand what you are trying to do ..